# how can I take data from a dynamic table row by row using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So basically I am looking for a way to take data from a dynamic table that is filled by the user and put it in a mysql database. The only part I am finding hard is reading row by row. Since this is a responsive dynamic table that lets the user add and delete rows, the name of the input tags remains the same row by row. Here is a sample of my code.

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="foo"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="bar"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="foo"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="bar"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="foo"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="bar"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array-notation, and this way when you post the values to the server - php will treat them as array:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="foo[]"> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="bar[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="foo[]"> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="bar[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="foo[]"> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="bar[]"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In your php code you will get

```
$_POST['foo'][0] = 'text1';
$_POST['foo'][1] = 'text2';
$_POST['foo'][2] = 'text3';
```

And this way you can have as many values as you want.

Comment: ah so basically I just need to add the brackets in my code? interesting, thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you need to do :)